# Wildfly 29| High CPU utilization when busy task count thread reaches the max io thread count

Tags: io, wildfly, cpu-usage

We are running into a problem with our application that uses JMS queues.

We receive a message in the queue -> triggers onMessage of MDB -> makes a calls to SOAP API over http(simultaneously a timed wait consumer is waiting for the response on the response queue)->response is written to response queue.

We are doing a load test and a pattern that we observe is when the response time from our backend is high(soap api) the default io threads are constantly reaching the threshold which is expected because of slow response. However, we see a huge spike in CPU (almost 8 cores being occupied). As soon as our backend starts responding better the spike comes down (so does the busy task thread count)

When we compare the thread dumps with high cpu usage and with optimal cpu usage, we see lot of blocked threads (around 190) which is waiting for a lock which is acquired by a TIMED-WAIT(Parked) thread.

### Blocked Thread sample: (Other 189 also are blocked waiting for the same lock)

"default task-1625" #3232 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=18990.56ms elapsed=1343.16s tid=0x00005575bffd9800 nid=0x51f8 waiting for monitor entry  [0x00007f3207a58000]
java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:860)
- waiting to lock <0x00000006acbc36f0> (a org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQJMSConnectionFactory)
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:335)
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:331)

### The above lock is owned by the following thread

"default task-2096" #3773 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=1309.26ms elapsed=149.43s tid=0x00005575c71ac000 nid=0x1b82 waiting on condition  [0x00007f321d487000]
java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(java.base@11.0.17/Native Method)
- parking to wait for  <0x000000079cfd9fd0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(java.base@11.0.17/LockSupport.java:234)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(java.base@11.0.17/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2211)
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ChannelImpl.sendBlocking(ChannelImpl.java:518)
- locked <0x000000079cfda010> (a java.lang.Object)
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ChannelImpl.sendBlocking(ChannelImpl.java:446)
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ActiveMQClientProtocolManager.createSessionContext(ActiveMQClientProtocolManager.java:306)
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ActiveMQClientProtocolManager.createSessionContext(ActiveMQClientProtocolManager.java:254)
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.createSessionChannel(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1419)
- locked <0x000000079cfd7608> (a java.lang.Object)
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.createSessionInternal(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:736)
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.createSession(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:317)
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnection.authorize(ActiveMQConnection.java:650)
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:901)
- locked <0x00000006acbc36f0> (a org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQJMSConnectionFactory)
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:335)

### Our Default IO thread configuration:

<worker name="default" **io-threads="200"** task-max-threads="200"/>

I am looking for insights on why the hike in CPU when busy task thread count reaches 200.

TIA

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQQTV.png)

in the thread dump took during cpu spike there are thread blocks ideally we would expect it to not consume CPU.